# How to create a table with lines and columns using Ireport?

Tags: ireport

I'am using JasperReport and ireport 4.0 , I want to know If their the possibility to create a table that can I fix lines and columns? Because the only the table that I have found allowed me just to fix columns !!

And

For the charts I have just an integer values but I dont know what the scale use float numbers!

**Update:**

what I mean that ireport allowed this format:

[image]

and I want the following format:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you have a varying number of rows, because the number of rows depend on the data from your database.

To have a known number of rows you either have to make sure that your data has the expected number of rows, or you design your detail section in a way that corresponds to your desired outcome. The height of the detail section is flexible, and you can put various text fields not only side by side, but also on top of each other.

Comment: ,oups ,sorry I have made a mistake I have updated your post :p